# Toggling accordion with jQuery manualy with nth-child(n)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle

Hi i have a quest with 4 steps.
The step have value one in the begginning, and every time when the user make a right thing the step++.

Now i have an explanation in accordion: section for every step.

So i want when the user make the right step it will slideUp the corrent step explanation, and slideDown the next one.

Here is what i got so far

```
acco=$('#accordion:nth-child('+this.step+')');

acco.slideToggle();
```

But seems it is not right...

Does any of you have an idea?

Thanks!

Update:

The function is so so big! But the in few words. i have an accordion like this

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Step1</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step2</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step3</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step4</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step5</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

</div>
```

For example Step1 section is open right now.

I want to write a function that will receive as a parameter a number of step and open the required section of explanation (and close all others)

```
openclose = function(step) {
acco=$('#accordion:nth-child('+step+')');
acco.slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: can you post the entire function or create a jsfiddle to explain your scenario better.

Comment: The function is so so big! But the in few words. i have an accordion like this
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Step1</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step2</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step3</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step4</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

<h3>Step5</h3>
<div>La la la</div>

</div>

For example Step1 section is open right now.

I want to write a function that will receive as a parameter a number of step and open the required section of explanation (and close all others)

openclose = function(step) {
acco=$('#accordion:nth-child('+step+')');
acco.slideToggle();
}

Comment: Hard to help you without seing even HTML. But the idea is to slideUp all the sections, and show the next one like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Yp2m/